# "Does not contain whitespace" in Code Contracts?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I'm new to Code Contracts - just starting to try to figure it out.  I just ran into something that I am not sure how to accomplish:

I have a certain private readonly field which can be publicly "got" via a property:

```
private readonly string name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

This field should never be null, should never be empty, and should never contain any white space.  So I put various "Requires" into the constructor to try to ensure those things:

```
public Thing(string name)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(
        name != null, 
        "Name must not be null");
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(
        name.Length > 0,
        "Name must have positive length");
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(
        !name.Any(x => char.IsWhiteSpace(x)),
        "Name must not include whitespace");

    this.name = name;
}
```

Putting in a little code to try to violate these contracts shows that the static checker successfully catches violations of "not null" and "not empty", but it does not catch violations of "contains no whitespace".  I guess this is unsurprising? I guess it does certain simple checks at compile time (like "!= null") but other more complicated ones (like the linq check for whitespace) aren't done except perhaps at runtime?

Anyway, I then added some invariants to the class to try to describe these same things:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ContractInvariants()
{
    Contract.Invariant(this.name != null);
    Contract.Invariant(this.name.Length > 0);
    Contract.Invariant(!this.name.Any(x => char.IsWhiteSpace(x)));
}
```

This resulted in the following warning (at least, with warning level set to high), on my constructor (quoted above):

```
CodeContracts: invariant unproven: !this.name.Any(x => char.IsWhiteSpace(x))
```

But the constructor is setting this.name to the value of a local variable that requires that same contract!

Are my Requires and/or my Invariant not doing what I intend them to do? Is there a way to make them do what I intend them to do? Should I even be trying to make them do what I intend them to do in the first place? Am I just fundamentally misunderstanding things here? Like I said, I'm totally new to this.  Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: `Contract.ForAll` may be worth giving a try, but I've had limited success with that myself.

Answer (score 1):

Code contracts aim to prove assumptions by *reasoning* about *requires* and *ensures* at compile time. But that problem is undecidable, so it is impossible to validate everything (not even with technology that will be invented within thousands of years, it is fundamentally - proven - impossible). Conservative algorithms can however prove a part of the statements and warn the programmer it is unable to prove other or prove that a contract will be harmed.

Your invariant has some problems that you call a *Linq* method within it, and that probably the *Linq* methods do not provide the (necessary) code contracts themselves to do the reasoning properly. You don't have to provide contracts for all methods. The system is sometimes able to reason about the code and reason about it oneself. But not always. For instance the code of an array list does not necessary provides an indication that the `Count` is always greater than or equal to zero...

Code contracts however have some builtin functions to work with collections like the `Contract.ForAll` functions:

```
Contract.Invariant(
    Contract.ForAll(this.name, x => !char.IsWhiteSpace(x))
);
```

This has more chance to get validated, but again, there is no guarantee this will change much. Neither that the code contract will get proven, nor proven false.

Comment: Thanks.  This doesn't seem to help, though (I do realize you said there's no guarantee that it would).  I changed both the Requires and the Invariant to use ForAll, and I still get the "invariant unproven" on it.  Also the static checker still doesn't trip when I intentionally add code to violate the Requires.

Comment: @BobVesterman: can you provide the scenario where you explicitly validate the constraint? Some things look simple from a human perspective but a system can also worry about exceptions,...

Comment: Sure: If I add some code to some other member function like this: `Thing t = new Thing(null);`, then I get a CodeContracts warning that invoking that member function will always lead to an error.  But if I instead add `Thing t = new Thing("white space in here");`, I get no such warning.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Contract.Invariant(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value))`instead. It will cover all three cases at once and the CodeContract engine might be able to support it at compile time too.

Comment: `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` is something else: say you have the string `"Foo Bar"`: it contains a space, but it is not `null` neither does it contain only whitespace...

Comment: Good point, I guess I misunderstood your question. In that case, CommuSoft's answer would be correct. Either way, you should still use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to merge your null and length contract into a single one.